# angular routing multiple paths to same component

Tags: angular

Is there a way to optimize this code from this

```
{
  path: 'access-requests',
  canActivate: [AccessGuard],
  component: AccessRequestsComponent,
  children: [
    {
      path: '',
      redirectTo: 'today',
      pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
      path: 'today',
      component: AccessRequestsComponent
    },
    {
      path: 'tomorrow',
      component: AccessRequestsComponent
    },
    {
      path: 'expired',
      component: AccessRequestsComponent
    }
    ]
}
```

to something like this

```
{
  path: 'access-requests',
  canActivate: [AccessGuard],
  component: AccessRequestsComponent,
  children: [
    {
      path: '',
      redirectTo: 'today',
      pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
      path: 'today | tomorrow | expired',
      component: AccessRequestsComponent
    }
    ]
}
```

Comment: may be it is possible using `regex`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use the [UrlMatcher](https://angular.io/api/router/UrlMatcher) property.

```js
    {
      path: 'access-requests',
      canActivate: [AccessGuard],
      component: AccessRequestsComponent,
      children: [
        {
          path: '',
          redirectTo: 'today',
          pathMatch: 'full'
        },
        {
          matcher: matcherFunction,
          component: AccessRequestsComponent
        }
        ]
    }
```

And

```js
    export function matcherFunction(url: UrlSegment[]) {
        if (url.length == 1) {
            const path = url[0].path;
             if(path.startsWith('today') 
               || path.startsWith('tomorrow') 
               || path.startsWith('expired')){
              return {consumed: url};
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Note: Untested code

Comment: Yes, one could use something like this. We can see how the [defaultUrlMatcher](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.4.5/packages/router/src/shared.ts#L112) does a path match as an example.

Comment: this is the correct answer, when you use this approach ... this.router.navigateByUrl does not try and reload the component when switching between the 2 (or more) paths

Comment: You could simplify the chain of `||` operators by using `['today', 'tomorrow'].some(p => path.startsWith(p))`.

Answer (score 29):

You can use a mapped array:

```js
children: [
  // excluding the other paths for brevity
  ...['today', 'tomorrow', 'expired'].map(path => ({
    path,
    component: AccessRequestsComponent
  }))
]
```

Comment: I realize the above is probably better practice, but this seems more readable to me.

Comment: @DaneBrouwer  thanks for the feedback! Regarding the "better practice" part: although more generic, the approach with the url matcher is slower, more intricate and not necessary (as there's no upside in our case). I think K.I.S.S. is a great practice

Comment: Honestly I didn't even think about the implications of using a custom url matcher - it just felt more Angular-like to me. However, I can't argue with K.I.S.S. or performance optimizations!

Comment: Note that this method will cause Angular to reload the component when switching between the different paths, which might or might not be what you want.

Comment: For me, It's showing the error: `ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
    at defaultUrlMatcher (router.js:525)` I'm using v9.

Answer (score 1):

Building on CornelC's answer, I wrote a method that accepts an array of string as paths and spits out a url matcher that will match an element of the array:

```js
    export const routingMatcher: ((paths: string[]) => UrlMatcher) = (paths: string[]) => {
      const result: UrlMatcher = (segments) => {
        const matchingPathIndex = paths.findIndex((path, index) => {
          const pathSegments = path.split("/");
          return segments.every((segment, i) =>
            pathSegments.length > i && (
              pathSegments[i].startsWith(":") ? true : segment.path.toLowerCase() === pathSegments[i].toLowerCase()));
        });
    
        if (matchingPathIndex >= 0) {
          const matchingPath = paths[matchingPathIndex];
    
          const consumed: UrlSegment[] = [];
          const params = {};
    
          matchingPath.split("/").forEach((path, i) => {
            consumed.push(segments[i]);
            if (path.startsWith(":")) {
              const param = path.substring(1);
              params[param] = segments[i];
            }
          });
    
          return {
            consumed: consumed,
            posParams: params
          };
        }
    
        return null;
      };
    
      return result;
    };
```

You can use it like this in your routing definitions:

```js
    children: [
      // excluding the other paths for brevity
        matcher:  routingMatcher(['today', 'tomorrow', 'expired'])
        component: AccessRequestsComponent
      }))
    ]
```