# Angular 5 - multiple routes same controller

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular-router

I've got routes defined like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: StartComponent},
  { path: 'route1', component: StartComponent},
  { path: 'route2', component: StartComponent},
  { path: 'route3', component: StartComponent}
];
```

Now if I navigate from route1 to route2, my StartComponent will be recreated. Is there any way to prevent angular doing that?

I've got some animations in this component and I need to switch between this routes without recreating my component.

Comment: Sorry - the subject should be - Angular 5 - multiple routes same component

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46364810/angular-routing-multiple-paths-to-same-component

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'route1', pathMatch: 'prefix'},
  { path: 'route/:routeId', component: StartComponent},
];
```

This should prevent the destruction of your component