# Load different components for different base href with same path name in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, routes

I've the following path's in my angular application, For `home` path base href is set to `/home/` and for create `/create/`

```
http://localhost:3000/home/account 
https://localhost:3000/create/account
```

**Dynamic Route Config path,**

```
export const AppRoute = {
  'homeRoutes': [
    { path: 'account', loadChildren: () => import('@home').then(m => m.HomeModule) },
    { path: 'test', loadChildren: () => import('@test').then(m => m.TestModule) },
    { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
  ],
  'createRoutes': [
    { path: 'account', loadChildren: () => import('@create').then(m => m.CreateModule) },
    { path: 'login-test', loadChildren: () => import('@logintest').then(m => m.LoginTestModule) },
    { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
  ]
};
```

**In AppComponent.ts**

```
  resetRouter () {
    const baseHref = this.platformLocation.getBaseHrefFromDOM();
    if (baseHref.match('/home/')) {
      this.router.resetConfig(routes.homeRoutes);
    }
    if (baseHref.match('/create/')) {
      this.router.resetConfig(routes.createRoutes);
    }
  }
```

**In Routing Module**

```
const routes =    [
    { path: 'home/account', loadChildren: () => import('@home').then(m => m.HomeModule) },
    { path: 'create/account', loadChildren: () => import('@home').then(m => m.HomeModule) },
    { path: 'test', loadChildren: () => import('@test').then(m => m.TestModule) },
    { path: 'login-test', loadChildren: () => import('@logintest').then(m => m.LoginTestModule) },
    { path: 'page-not-found', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];
```

So now the problem is,

My app now is now accessible only in `http://localhost:3000/home/home/account` which is not expected.

Also, If as access to `create` routes f.e `http://localhost:3000/home/test` works , but actual expectation is to throw error page.

Please help me configure these routes.

Comment: Why ... Why are you trying to route by breaking your router into 2 routers depending on the first piece of the path?? This is a very bad and hacky way of approaching the problem. Just keep the `baseHref` at `/` and make a route that captures both `home` and `create`. In that component you can check the `ActivatedRoute` and figure out whether you're in home or create, and in the HTML template display different content/components...

Comment: This is because my applications is deployed in `http://localhost:3000/MyAPP` , root is not belong to angular

Comment: Ok, so your `baseHref = '/MyAPP'` and it becomes `http://localhost:3000/MyAPP/home/account` and `http://localhost:3000/MyAPP/create/account`. That doesn't really matter

Answer (score 0):

I would change your approach. Since the routing config is just a constant you can duplicate your route config for both by unpacking a mapped array into the `routes` const (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62719724/1016004)):

```js
const routes =    [
    ...['home', 'create'].map(path => ({
      path: path, 
      component: BaseComponent,
      loadChildren: () => import('@home').then(m => m.HomeModule) 
    })),
    { path: 'test', loadChildren: () => import('@test').then(m => m.TestModule) },
    { path: 'login-test', loadChildren: () => import('@logintest').then(m => m.LoginTestModule) },
    { path: 'page-not-found', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];
```

Then inside of your `BaseComponent.ts` you use the `ActivatedRoute` API to figure out whether it's `home` or `create`:

```
public BaseComponent {
  public slug: string = undefined;
  construct(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.slug = this.route.snapshot.url[0].path;
  }
}
```

In the html use `*ngIf` to display either the `home` or `create` component:

```html
<app-home *ngIf="slug == 'home'"></app-home>
<app-create *ngIf="slug == 'create'"></app-create>
```

Comment: This doesn't work coz, `home` will have some specific set of routes which should not be accessible to `create`

Comment: Ok, fine, so then duplicate the config instead of using the array expansion :'D The ActivatedRoute approach remains the same and is preferable over the hacks you're trying to execute.