# How can I re-use a component instance in Angular 9 routing?

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

I'm trying to create a "blog-style" system. For this reason I also need a paging. My routing looks like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: PageComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                component: ResultsComponent,
            },
            {
                path: 'page/:page',
                component: ResultsComponent,
            },
        ],
    },
```

The `ResultsComponent` itself is a bit complex. Therefore I'm looking for a technique to re-use `ResultsComponent`. Currently, different component instances of `ResultsComponent` are created for `/` and `/page/5`. But it isn't really an option to do something like `/page/1`.

How can the desired behaviour be achieved?

Comment: Why not providing data to a service, and when the `url` changes you don't re-generate the component, only update the data according to something you can refer in the `url`, i.e. some id or number indicates a new result

Comment: @AbdulrahmanFalyoun but in any case the `ResultsComponent` is getting a new instance, isn't it?

Comment: When changing the `params` angular does not re-create a new component

Comment: Could find a working solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46364810/angular-routing-multiple-paths-to-same-component. The `UrlMatcher` is the key :-)